# Issue with generically casting a float with units to different units in F#

Tags: f#, units-of-measurement

I am having a major issue handling units of measure in F#. I have handled them successfully so far, but I have only either been removing units to get back a `float` or casting a `float` to one with units. However, now I have a use case where I need to generically drop units off of a float and give them new units. At present, I see no way that this is possible in F#.

For example:

```
> let removeUnits (x: float<'Unit>) = float x;;
val removeUnits: x: float<'Unit> -> float

> let castUnits<[<Measure>] 'Unit> (x: float) = LanguagePrimitives.FloatWithMeasure<'Unit> x;;
val castUnits: x: float -> float<'Unit>

> let convertUnits<[<Measure>] 'NewUnit> (x: float<'OldUnit>) : float<'NewUnit> =
    x |> removeUnits |> castUnits<'NewUnit>;;

  let convertUnits<[<Measure>] 'NewUnit> (x: float<'OldUnit>) : float<'NewUnit> =
  -------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^

stdin(8,47): warning FS0064: This construct causes code to be less generic than indicated by the type annotations. The unit-of-measure variable 'OldUnit has been constrained to be measure '1'.

val convertUnits: x: float -> float<'NewUnit>
```

This almost seems like a bug to me. The types of the pipeline *should be* `float<'OldUnit> -> float -> float<'NewUnit>`, because those are the type signatures of the component functions. I'm not understanding why out of nowhere that `'OldUnit` is being constrained to `1`.

How can I do this properly? I want a function with signature `val convertUnits: x: float<'OldUnit> -> float<'NewUnit>`, where the function only changes the units and leaves the underlying float values alone.

Is this a bug in the compiler?

Comment: As a general observation, units of measure are meant to add type safety. Removing the UoM removes that type safety.

Comment: That's true, but there are also practical constraints to using units of measure, both mathematically and in F#. They can't always be used. For example, it is not clear what units of measure are for matrices, but matrices can be used to transform a point, which may have units of measure. So rather than solve that sticky issue, it's easiest to simply remove the units from the point, multiply it by a matrix, and then reapply the units or give new units. To the caller of the function, the handling of the units is opaque: a point with units goes in, and a point with units comes out.

Comment: That certainly makes sense. I’m currently working on an already accepted RFC for F# to make working with, and converting to/from UoM’s a bit easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's just because you explicitly gave your function only one type parameter - `'NewUnit`, - but in its signature you're using two - `'OldUnit` and `'NewUnit`.

Give the function both parameters like this:

```
let convertUnits<[<Measure>] 'NewUnit, [<Measure>] 'OldUnit> (x: float<'OldUnit>) : float<'NewUnit> =
    x |> removeUnits |> castUnits<'NewUnit>
```

Or, alternatively, let the compiler infer them by itself:

```
let convertUnits (x: float<'OldUnit>) : float<'NewUnit> =
    x |> removeUnits |> castUnits<'NewUnit>
```

Comment: Thanks! The first solution by parameterizing the function for the old units works, but it is not clear why that is needed. Why does this type parameter need to be given to the function, when the argument already has it declared? For `'NewUnit` it makes sense. However, `removeUnits` doesn't need the unit type declared. This feels like a missed edge case in the compiler.

How is the second solution supposed to work? How does the compiler know what the new unit should be when calling this function? If I want to call it, I can only do `convertUnits 3.0<object>`, right?

Comment: `removeUnits` is using the second option - omitting type parameter declaration. A function always has as many type parameters as it has. You have the choice to declare them explicitly, like in option 1, or let the compiler infer them, like in option 2. But they're always there.

Comment: In particular, the second solution also has two type parameters. The fact that you don't have to write them out doesn't mean they're not there. The compiler can infer them for you, so you don't have to write them.

Comment: One way the compiler can know what the new unit should be is from context. For example, if you write `let x : float<foo> = converUnits 3.0<bar>`, the compiler knows that the new unit is `foo`, because that's the type of variable `x` where the result of `convertUnits` goes. The type of `x` doesn't have to be explicit either: it can come from somewhere else as well. And so on.

Comment: Another way the compiler can know is by specifying the function type parameters explicitly - as in `convertUnits<foo, bar> 3.0<foo>`. Note, however, that the order of parameters must be the same as in function declaration. If you don't explicitly specify type parameters at declaration site, it will be the order they appear in the signature. This is why it's better to specify them explicitly if you plan to specify them at call sites.

Comment: Finally, if some parameters can be known from context, but others can't, you can use wildcards to specify the known ones - for example, `convertUnits<_, bar> 3.0<foo>`

Comment: Yea, I let it slip from my mind to type annotation the variable I am assigning the result to. Although, I'm not crazy about that. I would rather specify it to the function.

Comment: However, it is still not clear to me why `let convertUnits<[<Measure>] 'NewUnit> (x: float<'OldUnit>) : float<'NewUnit>` doesn't work. I don't see a reason why `'OldUnit` needs to be parameterized but does not need to be parameterized in `removeUnits`. I don't see what's being inferred in `removeUnits`. And I don't understand the error message as to why it's being constrained to 1. I know about wildcards, and I understand the two solutions you provided. But I'm still confused on why the original gives the warning it does. The warning implies it knows it's a unit of measure but constrains it.

Comment: Once again: in the original, you explicitly specify one parameter, but the signature contains two. Honestly I think this should be an error, but F# instead makes the undeclared parameter `object`. There are only two legal way to specify type parameters: (1) specify all of them or (2) specify none of them. Your `removeUnits` function uses the second option. In my answer I offered both options for `convertUnits`. But your original `convertUnits` uses neither of those two legal ways.